# ¿ Como declarar una misma constante "let" para que exista en varias funciones dentro de una clase?

Tags: ios, swift

¿ Como se declara una constante let para que exista en varias funciones de una misma clase y la pueda llamar como self ?

Es decir, en objective-C bastaba con hacer antes de @implementation un @property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *variable; y luego en el método ( función ) que queramos usarla llamarla como self.variable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Debes declararla dentro de la clase y fuera de la función, en el siguiente ejemplo puedes apreciar la variable de clase "person" y dentro de las funciones se puede obtener su valor con "self.person" o sencillamente "person"

```
import Foundation

class MyClass {
    let person = "Harry";

    func hello() -> String {
        return "Hello, " + self.person + "!"
    }

    func bye() -> String {
        return "Bye, " + self.person + "!"
    }

    init() {
        print(hello())
    }
}

MyClass();
```

Comment: Para mi caso, inicialmente la variable o constante sera de tipo UIViewController y su valor se lo dare dentro de una función. Como tendría que declararlo entonces ? debería usar var en vez de let ?

Comment: 1. No se puede asignar un valor posterior a la definición a una variable estática en Swift, así no la instancies dado que el compilador marcara error.
2. Para hacer explicito el tipo de una variable se usa let person : String = "Harry" para el ejemplo que coloque.
3. La alternativa para lo que necesitas hacer seria hacer uso de una variable var con un singleton para el acceso a esta que impide su modificación posterior a la instancia.

Comment: ok, alfinal lo declare como var screen = UIViewController() dentro de la clase y fuera de la función. Dentro de la función le di un valor concreto.